# What test for categorical dependent variable? (Regression)

Tags: regression

I have one categorical dependent variable (non ordered) and several independent variables. Which regression model fits best here? Would it still be a multiple regression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a multivariable multinomial regression model.

It is multivariable because you have several independent variables.

It multinomial because the multinomial distribution can be used where the dependent variable is unordered categorical.

Comment: When I search for this in STATA I can only find "Multinomial logistic regression", would this be the same thing?

Comment: Yes, it is one and the same :)